# Which part is this pin with varying diameter?

Tags: part-identification

Can you tell me which part# is this?

[image: which part]

Answer (score 5):

The part is a [Technic, Pin 1/2 with 2L Bar Extension (Flick Missile)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=77562), part number 61184. It was released in 2008 and used extensively in the LEGO Agents theme as "flick missiles".

[image: Picture of Flick Missile]

Comment: And Star Wars sets.